# See an object only through another object in eevee

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I want to make a portal effect in which you can only see objects through another object in blender. I have found out how to do this in cycles, but not in eevee. I am okay if I have to do it in the compositor.[image]

In this picture I show the layout of the scene where I have a monkey inside of two objects, the one on the inside has an emission shader and the one on the outside has a transparent shader.

[image]

This picture shows the material for the portal. I want it to be invisible when seen through the outside object.

[image]

As you can see it works as intended in cycles. The light path node is making the monkey white when "outside" the portal and black when it is "inside". I need a way to replicate this effect inside of eevee. The transparent depth does not work in eevee. Is there a different way to make the effect in eevee or in the compositor?

Comment: You can use a Boolean modifier with intersect mode.